# Having trouble with ckeditor toolbar buttons

Tags: wysiwyg, toolbar

I cant figure out how the full toolbar can be view. I tried to toggle collapsed toolbar of and on however I am unable to see the either advanced toolbar or full (only some buttons I haven't selected at all). Meanwhile I can create the basic toolbar.

Can anybody help me get the full toolbar?

Comment: Uhhh I forgot. I haven't been able to select any users to the ckeditor profile. Does this have an impact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to configure CKEditor for a specific input format.

You might have an easier time if you install [WYSIWYG](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module AND the [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) editor. This setup will integrate better with the [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) module for instance. If you install WYSIWYG editor, you then can easily setup the editor per input format.

[image]

Comment: ahhh thank you...i mixed it with ckeditor for dupal